# Django: admin login page redirecting to itself

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am having a weird problem. I have a standard django 1.4 website with an admin section.

Locally everything is working fine, but when I deploy online, after login into the admin section the first time, it works. I logout then login again, then I get redirected to the same login page!

If I login with incorrect credentials then sure enough the correct errors are shown. If I restart the apache production server then login/logout to the admin section works only for one time then every login from then on produces the same problem.

Has anyone had this before? Is it something to do with cookies or maybe caching problems?

Note: The app has only one url redirecting to the admin, there are no other views. Also prodcution is using http and not https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well another one! There was a misspelling in the setting.py file in the TEMPLATE_DIRS entry. This appeard to be the source of the problem.